# Watir: ignore invalid Browser certificates

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to tell Google Chrome to ignore invalid Browser certificates with the command line switch from official documentation [1]:

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, switches: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
```

But I get the error:

> ArgumentError: {:switches=>["--ignore-certificate-errors"]} are
> unrecognized arguments for Browser constructor from
> /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/capabilities.rb:79:in
> `process_browser_options'
> 3.0.2 (dev)[1] »

How can I get rid of the error and tell Chrome to ignore the certificate?

[1] http://watir.com/guides/certificates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches get passed on the `args` parameter:

```
Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: {
  args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
})
```